# Ubuntu disk does not boot in UEFI mode

Tags: windows-8, uefi, aspire

The notebook (aspire v3 windows 8) doesn't even start in Uefi Mode. DVD drive is on top of the boot list. But Secure boot is deactivated. What could be the reason?

I'm sorry that I did not explain the problem in more detail. I'll try to explain more precisely:
Usually the logo of acer is displayed briefly and Windows loads shortly after that. When I start with the disk, the logo is displayed and the drive comes indeed to life, but then nothing happens. It just shows the logo.

Comment: Please describe your symptoms in more detail. For instance, after selecting the DVD drive in the firmware's boot manager, does the drive come to life? What (if anything) boots instead of the DVD-based Ubuntu installer? If nothing boots, does the computer hang or reboot entirely? Do you see any error messages? Does the screen change to the Ubuntu purple color?

Comment: The computer does nothing at all. It just displays the Logo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled UEFI boot in your BIOS? You can access that under the Advanced Settings tab for your BIOS - you can access the settings by pressing F8 (or F2 or F10) when you see your manufacturers logo during boot up. It should be the first logo you should see.

Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I bought the laptop pre-installed with Windows 8. UEFI and secure boot were enabled initially. I am using ubuntu-gnome-13.04-desktop-amd64.

Comment: I'd recommend trying 12.04 LTS. LTS stands for long term support. This means that 12.04 is a very stable version that Ubuntu will continue to push updates for until 2017.

All of the newer versions are supported only for months (13.04 is supported for 9 months only) because Ubuntu is continuously making changes to it. They are almost like sneak peeks at work in progress, which means there is less community adoption, less support and more issues. 

The next LTS version is 14.04, so I would highly recommend waiting to upgrade until that comes out.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. However, I prefer to use Gnome 3 and 12.04 is unfortunately only with Unity. I tried it once and did not like the design of Unity at all. Apart from that I think that the newer versions better cope with UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Something of a long shot, but try this:

1. Download the USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Prepare a USB flash drive with rEFInd.
3. Reboot and tell the computer to boot from the USB flash drive, with the Ubuntu DVD in your DVD drive. rEFInd should appear, and it should give options to boot Windows and to boot from the DVD. If you don't see a DVD option, hit Esc to tell rEFInd to re-scan your devices.
4. Select the DVD option in rEFInd.

This *might* fix the problem, and even if it doesn't, the way it fails might provide more clues about what's going wrong.

Another option is to copy the Ubuntu DVD image to a USB flash drive. If you've got an existing Linux system, use `dd` for this, as in `sudo dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdc` to copy `image.iso` to the USB flash drive on `/dev/sdc`. *Be very careful with this command!* A mistake can do serious damage to the target device (specified via `of=`). Once Ubuntu's on the USB flash drive, you can try booting from it.